# slick slider for rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Want to install the [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider in my rails app. Installed the gem [jQuery-slick-rails](https://github.com/bodrovis/jquery-slick-rails).
Add `//= require jquery.slick`  into your `application.js`.
Add `*= require slick` and `*= require slick-theme` into your `application.css`.
Add file `autoplay.coffe` and add into `application.js`:

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.autoplay').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
```

As html:

```
<div class="slider autoplay slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Doing for example this [demo](https://github.com/bodrovis/jquery-slick-rails-demo).

But the code does not work. I think got that wrong.

**How to connect the code to autoplay?**
**how to connect any code from the [demo slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)?**

Comment: I believe this is an issue with turbolinks. I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the call to slick() on `turbolinks:load` , add it on `document.on(ready)`. It should work!
Or , move the script into the view page